# screw mount cooler on 1151 mobo?

Tags: motherboard, mount, cooling

I am building a briefcase PC, looking at going with a G4560 in a Gigabyte H110m. My I went ahead and put some old parts in the box and ran a stress test and it became quite hot with the circular cooler I was using because there isn't as many escapes for air in the briefcase (obviously) so I was looking at low-profile side blowing coolers. the best one I have found is this: http://www.frozencpu.com/products/10079/cpu-dyn-45/Dynatron_K650_2U_Server_Active_CPU_Cooler_-_Intel_Socket_LGA_115x.html

It says it is made for socket 1156, alot of people online say that 115x coolers should work for 1151 just fine. my question is, will the cooler listed above work with this motherboard: [https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813145010&cm_re=gigabyte_h110m-*-13-145-010-*-Product](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813145010&cm_re=gigabyte_h110m-_-13-145-010-_-Product)

more: I have worked with alot of computers, since I have never done a skylake build i missed out on the screw mounts and i've only personally worked with the push-pin mounts, the cooler listed above is a screw mount and my z170 board was a push-pin mount, are they compatible????

Comment: [Yes](http://www.dynatron-corp.com/?product=k650) it does

Answer (score 1):

> The cooler listed above is a screw mount and my z170 board was a
>   push-pin mount, are they compatible?

You would need a mounting kit in order to make them compatible.  The [Dynatron K650](http://www.dynatron-corp.com/?product=k650) itself is indeed compatible with socket 1151.  I suggest just sending an inquiry to Dynatron to determine what additional parts you will need to purchase.

> CPU Socket    **LGA 1151**, LGA 1155, LGA 1156